# Change Notebook's Default Context

Tags: packages

In my workflow, when testing/developing packages, It's an common situation to test internal packages functions that has been already loaded with the package, so they are in the `` MyPackage`Private `` context.

Today I know 2 options to test these functions.

1- Use full name like: `` Mypackage`Private`myFunction[x] ``

2- Comment `` Begin["`Private`"] `` and `End[]`, and run the package again.

Number 1 is very verbose. Number 2 is dangerous (I sometimes forgot to uncomment it).

**My question is:**

There is another way to do that?

I tested the menu option: Notebook Default Context -> Other... But without success.

Comment: In such situations, I usually just add private context to `$ContextPath` like this: `If[FreeQ[$ContextPath, #], 
   PrependTo[$ContextPath, #]] &@"MyPackage`Private`"`. But I've just tried changing `Notebook Default Context` and it worked for me, so what precisely is not working in your case?

Comment: You can make an input cell with the CellContext being ``MyPackage`Private` ``. Then you can use short names for private functions in that cell. You can automate creation of such cells with a palette or e.g. docked cell in your particular notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `` Begin["Mypackage`Private`"] ``, then call `myFunction[x]` and any other private functions, followed by `End[]` in your test notebook or .mt file instead of commenting it in the package.

This way you don't need to modify your package, you only need to write out the context once and it will work the same way every time you run the code, regardless of notebook context options or the value of `$ContextPath`.